# Cambridge IELTS 10 example essay. Adj or Adv after a verb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Here is a sentence from the example essay of Cambridge IELTS 10, Test 1:

"*This kind but firm approach will achieve more than harsh punishment, which might entail many negative consequences **unintended** by the parents.*"

My question is that why a adjective "unintended" is used after a verb "entail"?

Comment: It seems fine where it is. Why does its placement look odd to you?

Answer (score 1):

"Unintended" is a past participle that introduces a **passive**, reduced relative clause

"many negative consequences **unintended** by the parents." = many negative consequences **that were unintended** by the parents."

Compare the use of the continuous participle that introduces an **active** reduced relative clause

"many negative consequences **surprising** the parents." =many negative consequences **that surprised** the parents."

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Then I understand that "unintended" is used to modify "consequences".  Can I rewrite the sentence as ",which might entail many unintended negative consequences by the parents"?

Answer (score 1):

> *This kind but firm approach will achieve more than harsh punishment*,
> *which might entail many negative consequences* [*unintended by the*
> *parents*].

"Unintended" is not an adjective here, but a past participle verb heading the bracketed past-participial clause modifying "consequences".

Past-participials (and gerund-participials) as modifiers in noun phrase structure are semantically similar to relative clauses: cf. "negative consequences which are unintended by the parents", but we don't analyse them as relative clauses since there is no possibility of them containing a relative phrase (cf. *"consequences which unintended by the parents").

Past-participial modifiers are 'bare' passives, as evident from the admissibility of a *by* phrase.